# I want to publish comment on different facebook pages from my site, is it possible?

Tags: facebook-page

I'm working on a website which is a media website. On my website I've different shows in a dropdown and I've created different pages on facebook for all those shows. I can select show from the dropdown and give some comment in the comment box on my website. Now, can I post this comment on the facebook page for the show which is selected from the dropdown? Is it possible? If possible then please provide the code to do this.

Thanks for your help

Comment: gimnme teh codez in a mailbox

Answer (score 1):

> If possible then please provide the code to do this.

plz send me teh codez questions are generally not "acceptable" on StackOverflow.

Your solution is to supply the `to` field of the FB.ui's `feed` method and set it to the page id value selected in your dropdown.

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        to: facebookPageId,
        link: urlToShare
}, 
    function(response) {
        if(response && response.post_id) alert('Posted!');
});
```

More information on the FB.ui can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/